# Dynamic text field after select combo box data (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, combobox

I want to make dynamic text field named `HOLIDAY` after one of data at combo box has selected.

The column which display at combo box is `PROBLEM`.
For example I have five problems are A, B, C, D, E.

When I select A problem on combo box, the form edit will display dynamic text field name `HOLIDAY` without reload the page. But, If I select B, C, D, E, It doesn`t display. Just A problem which have dynamic text field.

So, how can I solve this problem?
What is the code for controller, model, and view on codeigniter?

Comment: What code do you currently have which isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the code bellow:

**HTML**

```
<select id="combo" name="combo">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A problem</option>
    <option value="B">B problem</option>
    <option value="C">C problem</option>
    <option value="D">D problem</option>
    <option value="E">E problem</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#combo").change(function(){
        var $comboValue = $(this).val();
        if($comboValue == "A"){

            //Dynamically create the textbox
            var $template = "<input type='text' name='HOLYDAY' id='HOLYDAY' placeholder='HOLYDAY' />";

            $(this).parent().append($template);
        } else {
            $("#HOLYDAY").remove();   
        }
    });
});
```

Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kqpn3rc/) to live preview

Regards

Comment: How can I connect the html and jsp file. Is it become two file or just one file? sorry, I`m still amateur. I already have view.php form which use to display form, model.php to setting query sql, and controlling.php to call model and view file